# Find possible values of $y$ such that $\sqrt{2^y + 1}$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

How can I find the values of $y$ such that $\sqrt{2^y + 1}$ is a perfect square ?

I cant really understand how to proceed. By trial, I see that $y = 3$ is a possible solution, but how can I check for higher values of $y$. Any hints/explanations are appreciated!

Comment: If $2^a=n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$ then you need both $n\pm 1$ to be powers of $2$.

Comment: Oh! thanks @lulu so n=3 must be the only solution possible

Comment: @ashish: since $n+1=n-1+2$, that is the only solution

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\sqrt{2^y +1} = n$.
Then $$2^y =n^2-1 = (n-1)(n+1)$$
So $n-1$ and $n+1$ should be powers of $2$, say $2^k$ and $2^l$ respectively with $k >l$. Then we have
$$2^k -2^l =2 $$
$$2^{l}(2^{k-l}-1)=2 $$
$$\implies 2^{k-l}-1 =1,  2^l =2  $$
$$\implies k-l =1 , \ l=1$$
That is, $k=2, l=1$ giving us the only solution $n =2^l +1 = 3$